# For of a method get of a hash table

Tags: get, hashtable

Why this `for` stops when `key[i] == null`, I don't really understand it, I'll appreciate you help me with this question!

```
public Val get(Key key) {
    int i;
    for (i = hash(key); keys[i] != null; i = (i+1) % M)
        if (keys[i].equals(key)) break;
    return vals[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `for (A; B; C)`, `A` runs once at the start, then if `B` is `true` it executes the loop once, then it executes `C` and checks `B` again.  As soon as `B` is `false`, the loop terminates.

In your case, if `key[i] == null` then `B` is `false`, and that's why the `for` loop stops.